# Not able to generate Fcm Token while hosting firebase app through localhost

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
  const messaging = firebase.messaging();
  messaging.requestPermission()
  .then(function(){
  console.log("Permission Granted");
  return messaging.getToken();
})
```

I am trying to connect to firebase messaging to generate token, which can later be used for push notifications, I have connected the local project with firebase
and started used firebase server for local host, but the token is not getting generated.[image]

Answer (score 0):

please send the serviceworker file to the directory where the project is hosted